# Jira: Error connecting to database

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, jira, amazon-rds

1. I created a MySQL RDS instance at AWS(Amazon web services).When I tried to test connection(Database) during the "Jira" installation, I am facing the below issue:

> Error connecting to database
>   Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
>   Connection timed out: connect

2. when I tried to connect through MySQL localhost I am facing the below issue:

> Error connecting to database
>   Unknown system variable 'storage_engine'

Comment: Go look for similar question and answer under serverfault.com .

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove 'storage_engine' variable from db url in  /var/atlassian/application-data/jira/dbconfig.xml.
New mysql does not support this parameter as it is default engine now.